# Concurrency With Static Variables

Tags: c#, concurrency, static-variables

Maybe its too late, but I have a static class for the sake of global variables in my winforms application. Now, I am realizing this may cause issues. The question is: **"With the static class variables in my application, will it raise concurrency issues while its running in multi-user environment?".**

If this is true, can anyone suggest a way to overcome it?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Does the application use the same instance for multiple users?

Comment: Need more problem definition (e.g. "multi-user environment", concurrency issues).

Comment: If you do all your work on the UI thread, then this probably won't be a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **No**. Multi user environment means that multiple users are using your program, *but every one is starting a new instance*. Your static variables will not be shared across multiple processes and hence will only be a problem once your program consists of multiple threads.

However, static global variables are not a "good thing" (tm). You should avoid them because they will lead to problems once you *do* have multiple threads running in your process.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer :
Yes,
Simply use lock to prevent the concurrency issue when you try to modify the variable.

Comment: Sorry, I am a novice coder in C#, don't if you find my question silly. Here, by locking what do you mean, does synchronize works with static variables?

Answer (score 0):

First, global variables are a bad idea, you should avoid using globals where possible.

If multiple threads are reading and writing to the same variables, you have a concurrency problem, yes. To avoid this, read/write the global variables on a single thread.

If you're unable to do that, you can [lock access to the variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx).